# "library not found for -lcocos2d libraries" after associating new cocos2d framework

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Im getting the below build errors after reassociating all of the 'cocos2d sources' files into my project to update it from 0.99.0 to 0.99.3. Any clues what might be causing this or do I have to create a new project with the appropriate template and associate the proper files into the new project?

PS. I am not upgrading to the newest version as it requires Lion or an Apple developer license which I have not yet procured.

```
    Building target “Puzzle” of project “Puzzle” with configuration “Debug”


Checking Dependencies

Ld "/Users/Sup3rpanda/Dev/My Projects/Builds/Debug-iphonesimulator/Puzzle.app/Puzzle" normal i386
    cd "/Users/Sup3rpanda/Dev/My Projects/Puzzle"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk "-L/Users/Sup3rpanda/Dev/My Projects/Builds/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/Sup3rpanda/Dev/My Projects/Builds/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/Sup3rpanda/Dev/My Projects/Builds/Puzzle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Puzzle.build/Objects-normal/i386/Puzzle.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -all_load -ObjC -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -lz -framework AVFoundation "-lcocos2d libraries" -o "/Users/Sup3rpanda/Dev/My Projects/Builds/Debug-iphonesimulator/Puzzle.app/Puzzle"
ld: library not found for -lcocos2d libraries
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, there was a 'libcocos2d.a' being built as a target. Removing that allowed me to successfully build again.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3384